# How to make Vuetify v-for render faster

Tags: html, vue.js, for-loop, vuetify.js, v-for

Hello i am new in vuejs and vuetify, i am now want to display item about 400colums and 6 rows, colum_id (cid) and row_id(rid) but render speed is slow sorry may i know how to improve this loop performance Thank before hand :[image]

```
<v-layout>
      <div class="reglahan-table-result-betting">
        <tr
          v-for="i in 6"
          :key="i">
          <td
            v-for="j in 60"
            :key="j">
            <div
              v-for="(item, k) in props.resultBetting"
              :key="k">
              <span
                v-if="Number(item.cid) === j && Number(item.rid) === i"
                :class="item.color"
              />
            </div>
            <span class="no-circle" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </div>
    </v-layout>
```

Comment: You have a triple nested loop, hard to make that very performant, and the more data you have the slower it's going to get. Perhaps a refactor is in order to help reduce this complexity

Comment: 400 columns? I see 60 columns. Also innermost loop looks very strange. You render one `div` for every item in `resultBetting` but all are empty except one corresponding to current column/row index. Why ?

Comment: [According to the documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State), you can increase performance by removing `:key`. But you have to be aware of the side effects. Reordering the elements will then no longer be possible.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can optimize that. The problem is that in your most inner loop, you loop on every element of the array. You shouldn't do that.

First you need to properly index your table, I would create a 'computed' function as such :

```
computed: {
  indexedResultBetting: function () {
    let ret = {}
    self.props.resultBetting.forEach(function(item, index){
      if(!item.rid in ret)
        ret[item.rid] = {}
      ret[item.rid][item.cid] = item.color
    })
    return ret
  }
}
```

Then you can simply show that with something like :

```
<v-layout>
  <div class="reglahan-table-result-betting">
    <tr
      v-for="i in Object.keys(indexedResultBetting)"
      :key="i">
      <td
        v-for="j in Object.keys(indexedResultBetting[i])"
        :key="j">
        <div          
          <span
            :class="indexedResultBetting[i][j]"
          />
        </div>
        <span class="no-circle" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </div>
</v-layout>
```

I haven't tested it, there is certainly some tinkering to do.

Comment: thank you for your sharing, your code is load faster than before 3 or 4 times but the problem is it is not display data correctly, all data display as a line. thank you